# Could not interpret "{}" as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

So i'm developing a discord bot and i want to make a command that when the user types ".doggo" a random image of a dog appears. This is the code i have for the current command. I have the node-fetch and discord.js libraries installed to the application already.

```
else if(command === 'doggo') {
    const Fetch = fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random');
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('doggo :dog:')
    .setImage(Fetch);
    message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

For some reason I'm getting this warning message when the command is executed:

```
(node:10416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.image.url: Could not interpret "{}" as string.
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\jnett\Desktop\demon\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:10416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10416) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

What's wrong with my code? what do i need to do to fix it?

Comment: `fetch()` is asynchronous and returns a promise

Comment: what does that api returns?

Answer (score 0):

The `fetch()` call is asynchronous and will cause you issues if not treated as such. Read more about the Fetch API here:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

Regarding the error messages...

1. `Invalid Form Body` is due to trying to embed an image that has not yet been received by your node app. This can be avoided by capturing the subsequent code that uses the data from the fetch call in the `.then(() => { })` callback.
2. `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` and `DeprecationWarning` (and technically the first error) are due to the lack of the `.catch()` callback. This is where you can specify what to do if the fetch request cannot be fulfilled.